# PHP Order Form - Email with Attachment

Tags: php, email, attachment

I am trying to create an order form which when complete, passes you on to the order.php page (sends the email), where you are then passed on to paypal. Everything was working fine until i tried to add attachments, when i added the code for attachment, the email is no longer sent.

```
<?php 

$to = 'hidden' ; 
$from = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ; 
$headers = "From: $from"; 
$subject = "Distinctive Writers - Contact Form"; 
$tprice = $_REQUEST['tprice'] ;

$fields = array(); 
$fields{"name"} = "name";  
$fields{"email"} = "email"; 
$fields{"number"} = "number"; 
$fields{"subject"} = "subject"; 
$fields{"doctype"} = "doctype";
$fields{"spec"} = "spec";
$fields{"grade"} = "grade";
$fields{"days"} = "days";
$fields{"due"} = "due";
$fields{"pages"} = "pages";
$fields{"price"} = "price";

$mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

$tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
$file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];

if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

  // Check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
  if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

     // Now Open the file for a binary read
     $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

     // Now read the file content into a variable
     $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

     // close the file
     fclose($file);

     // Now we need to encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
     $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
 }

// Now we'll build the message headers
  $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
     "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
     " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

   // Now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as an attachment, then add the file content and set another boundary to indicate that the end of the file has been reached
  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
     " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
     //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
     //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";


$body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){    $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

$headers2 = "From: noreply@YourCompany.com"; 
$subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
$autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.oursite.com";

if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
else { 
if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
else { 
$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $message); 
$send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 

}
}

if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, $message)){
print "ERROR!!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a library like PHPMailer, because constructing vaild headers for any mail-client is headbanging!

Comment: I didn't know if PHPMailer was appropriate because i looked at sample code and it showed a pre-defined file (not an upload of the users's choice). 

"$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment"

Comment: $mail->AddAttachment("$file"); Read thru the examples....

Answer (score 0):

I recommend PHPMailer too as mentioned by pc-shooter

then you can use

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

then you can utilize either one of these two

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($string,$filename)
$mail->AddAttachment($path);
```

Something to keep in mind, something else might be blocking the email. if the mail function returns TRUE then the mail was dispatched.